# RxJava2 - Concat multiple observables, prevent execution if first element found

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java2

Im working on implementing simple data provider with 2 level cache using RxJava2

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Observable.concat(getFromMemory(), getFromFileCache(), getFromNetwork())
            .firstElement()
            .subscribe((integer) ->
            {
                System.out.println("Completed with val: " + integer);
            });
}

static Observable<Integer> getFromMemory() {

    return Observable.create(e -> {
        System.out.println("Source: Memory");
        e.onNext(1);
        e.onComplete();
    });
}

static Observable<Integer> getFromFileCache() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Observable.create(e -> {
        System.out.println("Source: FileCache");
        e.onNext(2);
        e.onComplete();
    });
}

static Observable<Integer> getFromNetwork() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Observable.create(e -> {
        System.out.println("Source: Network");
        e.onNext(3);
        e.onComplete();
    });
}
```

Goal is to look for object in memory cache, 
if not found - read from file, if not found - call network to get resource. Cache update is not important in this sample.

When executing this code, I see console log:

```
Source: Memory
Source: FileCache
Source: Network
Completed with val: 1
```

Which mean file cache and network call will be executed, despite memory cache returns value. 
Im using rxJava 2, which operator can I use, to combine sources, but stop executing on first valueFound? I experimented with first(default) and take, no luck so far

Answer (score 0):

Actually, its a bug in rxJava2 - upgrading to 2.1.0 helped:

Github issue: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/5100